# Error Question: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python

I am trying to create a tribonacci program. Similar to fibonacci, it sums up the last three elements in the iterable. E.g. [1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, ...] (1+1+1=3, 1+1+3=5). However, there is an error that I cannot understand: `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`

I tried this and expected the output: `[1, 1, 1, 3]`

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    array = []
    array.append(signature)
    for i in range(n):
        if i < 3:
            array.append(signature[i])
        else:
            array.append(sum(array[i-3:i]))
    return array

tribonacci([1,1,1], 4)
```

`signature` is an array of the first three numbers to be added to the tribonacci.

Comment: A print(array) at the end of your loop might give you a hint on how it looks like and why a list is added to an int. Think about what your 3 append statements do and which of them could be problematic.

Comment: The first element of `array` is the `signature` list. The rest of the elements are numbers. You can't get the `sum()` of this.

Comment: I suspect what you actually want is to initialize `array` with a copy of `signature`: `array = signature.copy()`

Comment: Why are you doing `array.append(signature)` in the first place? The code works perfectly if you just remove that part. Anyway, Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, and this isn't a question. Please take the [tour], check out [ask], and [edit] to clarify what you want to ask. Like to start, do you understand what the error means? What part are you confused about?

Comment: Showing the entire error trace would probably make this a lot clearer, since your code doesn't have a `+` in it.

Comment: @Mark I have a template with a link to more info about that: *please post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)*

Comment: Sidenote: `array` is a potentially misleading name for a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is in line `array.append(signature)`. Let's look at what happens to `array` on each iteration by printing out its contents:

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    array = []
    array.append(signature)
    for i in range(n):
        print(i, array)
        if i < 3:
            array.append(signature[i])
        else:
            print(array[(i-3):i])
            array.append(sum(array[(i-3):i]))
    return array
tribonacci([1,1,1],4)
```

Output:

```
0 [[1, 1, 1]]
1 [[1, 1, 1], 1]
2 [[1, 1, 1], 1, 1]
3 [[1, 1, 1], 1, 1, 1]
[[1, 1, 1], 1, 1]
```

The first element is always a list (your initial list), which doesn't make a lot of sense. And when row `array.append(sum(array[(i-3):i]))` is supposed to be executed for the first time `array` contains both list and integers, which python doesn't know how to sum up.

So if you get rid of `array.append(signature)` everything will work nicely.